Chrome Extension Manifest 3 GIF not showing
I am developing an extension for Google Chrome that is supposed to show a GIF in overlay at the end of a timer.
The timer works just fine, but the image doesn't get shown.
background.js
let timerId = null;

// Function to start the timer
function startTimer(duration) {
  // Clear existing timer
  if (timerId) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  }

  // Set new timer
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    // Inject content script into the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      const tabId = activeTab.id; // Get the ID of the active tab
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId, allFrames: true }, // Use the tabId obtained above
        files: ['contentScript.js'],
      });
    });

    console.log("Timer ended");
  }, duration * 1000); // Convert seconds to milliseconds
}

// Listen for messages from the popup script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === 'startTimer') {
    const duration = message.duration;
    console.log("Received duration:", duration);
    startTimer(duration); // Start the timer
  }
});

contentScript.js
// Create a semi-transparent overlay
const overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.style.position = 'fixed';
overlay.style.top = '0';
overlay.style.left = '0';
overlay.style.width = '100%';
overlay.style.height = '100%';
overlay.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'; // Semi-transparent black
overlay.style.zIndex = '9999'; 
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

// Create an image element
const imgSrc = 'AAA.gif'; 
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = imgSrc;
img.style.position = 'fixed';
img.style.top = '50%';
img.style.left = '50%';
img.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
img.style.zIndex = '10000';
document.body.appendChild(img);


setTimeout(function() {
  overlay.remove();
  img.remove();
}, 2000); 

I tried changing the approach and, if I create another tab after the timer, the GIF it's shown accordingly. But I need it to work as above, instead of creating another tab.
I tried creating a notification after the timer, but the notification doesn't get created.


To use executeScript you need to declare host_permissions in manifest.json. 2) It can't inject into the built-in UI pages including the start page and in pages of other extensions. 3) Timeout longer than 30 seconds will fail because the service worker will unload (workarounds).

